# Securing Rest API for mobile applications and micro-services using spring boot

Tags: api, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, microservices

We are developing few micro-services using spring boot.These Rest API's will be consumed by mobile application. What is the best and recommended ways to secure these API's for mobile application using the spring boot framework itself. I'am not experienced with securing the api's for mobile applications. 
Your advice's are highly appreciated here.

Need to consider these areas.

- How to generate tokens
- How to store token
- How to refresh them and expire them.
- When the mobile application should receive the token

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using ready-to-use solutions for Identity Management like an open-source [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org) or paid providers like [Auth0](https://auth0.com) instead of reimplementing the wheel of security on your own. There are simple Spring Security adapters for both named options.

The typical approach is to use [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/) with Authorization Code Grant Flow extended with PKCE (https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/pkce/).